# Pass output of one command as input to other

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, linux-mint, pipelining

I have searched one file "portmap" inside root directory as follows:

```
find -name "portmap"
```

It gives location of file

```
.init/...somepath./portmap
```

Now I want to change my current directory to the location of portmap file and print the present working directory.

So I am  thinking of pipeline the above location to cd. But how can I do it with one command?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that `find` finds one and only one match for the search pattern, you can use

```
cd "$( dirname "$( find -name "portmap" )" )"
```

If at any time you want to do to the directory enumerated in the output of the previous command, you can use

```
cd "$( dirname "$(!!)" )"
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. But it gives me error basedir command not found. I just copy pasted above line. Does this work in mint command prompt? Thanks

Comment: @techfun I think DopeGhoti meant `dirname`. Also, you should double-quote the substitutions to prevent paths with spaces from breaking the command.

Comment: Yes, I did, thanks @slhck.  For some reason, I get the `basename` and `dirname` wires crossed in my head every time.

Comment: Happy to have helped.

Answer (score -1):

The xargs command is perfect for this, but the cd command in the shell doesn't play well with it. So I'd use back ticks:

```
cd `find . -type d -name "portmap"`
```

Comment: The OP wants to go to the directory where the file `portmap` is contained. Your command does not achieve that. Also, double quotes should be used when substituting file paths.